# Sequelize select * where attribute is NOT x

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

looking at the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll) you can use 
    `model.findAll({where: {attribute: x}})`. However, I want to select all attributes that are simply NOT x. I was looking into a regular expression here but that seemed like not an optimal solution.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this

```
model.findAll({where: {attribute: { $not: 'x'}}})
```

---

Sequelize actually provides many operators for you to get your filter data.

You can refer to the link [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html)

Comment: Update: now you are supposed to use operators: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators

Comment: The operators page has moved to https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#operators

Answer (score 73):

Updated method, for modern Sequelize:

```
model.findAll({
  where: {
    someAttribute: {
      [sequelize.Op.not]: 'some value'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You can add more values ```[sequelize.Op.not]: ['value1','value2'...]```

Answer (score 7):

Use [Op.ne] operator. ne is an operator for not equal to. Remember to import { Op } from 'sequelize';

```
model.findAll({
      where: {
        attribute: {[Op.ne]:'x'} /*eg status: {[Op.ne]:'pending'}*/
      }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 6):

Please note the `$not:'x` is deprecated and does not work in the latest version.

Now we can use `[Op.gt` instead:

```
model.findAll({
  where: {
    attribute: {[Op.not]:'x'}
  }
});
```

Please find more details [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html)